# After selecting value from spinner, remaining all fields has to be enabled

Tags: java, android, xml

On my Activity, First user need to select value from spinner then only remaining all fields has to be enabled, otherwise I need to display message to user "please select the value". How can I achieve this? Can any one give me solution with sample application.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your code what you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write code for enabling other fields in `onItemSelected`,

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```

But note that, `onItemSelected` is also called on initializing `setOnItemSelectedListener` first time.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the code snippet:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Spinner spinner;
private EditText name;
private EditText city;
private Button btnSubmit;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bindViews();
    validate();

}

private void bindViews(){
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    name = findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
    city = findViewById(R.id.edt_city);
    btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    name.setFocusable(false);
    city.setFocusable(false);
}


private void validate(){
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String spinnerValue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Log.d("spinner",spinnerValue);
            if(spinnerValue.equals("Select")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Select a value from spinner",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }else{
                name.setFocusable(true);
                city.setFocusable(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}